# Parametrizing SQL script

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement

I have to make

```
SELECT column1,column2
INTO OUTFILE 'out_1.csv'
FROM table1
WHERE column1.name = '1'

SELECT column1,column2
INTO OUTFILE 'out_2.csv'
FROM table1
WHERE column1.name = '2'

SELECT column1,column2
INTO OUTFILE 'out_3.csv'
FROM table1
WHERE column1.name = '3'
```

and so on...
I thought it was a good idea to do something like:

```
SELECT column1,column2
INTO OUTFILE 'out_$1.csv'
FROM table1
WHERE column1.name = $1
```

and pass the parrameter $1 through a UNIX shell script. But maybe there's a better way.
There is a SQL "native" way to iterate through a range from 1 to 40?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. You can create a stored procedure and use [LOOP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/loop-statement.html) or [WHILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/while-statement.html).

Comment: Do I NEED to create a stored procedure?

Comment: How to expand the value of a counter INT variable into a MySQL STRING?

Comment: @user869097 Use [`CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat).

Comment: sorry but the usage of WHILE in MySQL is not so trivial at all for my example query above, if you have a link with a WHILE example WITHOUT printing the output of a crappy counter it would be really cool

Comment: In your example above the `WHERE` clause is, indeed, very simple. If you have a variable you can use it both in your `WHERE` clause directly and in `INTO OUTFILE` with e.g. `CONCAT('out_', @somevar, '.csv')`. This is all in the docs and there's valuable info in the comments too.