# Declaring a variable for using as parameter in stored mysql procedure

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement

I'm trying to implement a [simple counter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004370/parametrizing-sql-script) which is passed as parameter in several statements in a SQL query (see below). I have the following test environment

```
CREATE TABLE `test`.`TableA` (
`ColumnA` INT( 3 ) NOT NULL ,
`ColumnB` INT( 5 ) NOT NULL
) ENGINE = MYISAM ;

ALTER TABLE `TableA` ADD INDEX ( `ColumnA` ) 

INSERT INTO `TableA` (`ColumnA`, `ColumnB`) VALUES 
(2, 4654), (2, 223), (5, 12), (4, 32), (3, 23), (5, 21), (1, 2), (2, 2), (4, 2), (5, 1);
```

I want a numbered output file for each counter iteration (and AFAIK one way to do this is to use a stored procedure)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dowhile()
BEGIN
  DECLARE CONT INT DEFAULT 5
  WHILE CONT > 1 DO
  BEGIN
        SELECT TableA.ColumnB
        INTO OUTFILE CONCAT('OUT', CONT)
        FROM TableA
        WHERE TableA.ColumnA = CONT
    SET CONT = CONT - 1
  END
  END WHILE
END;
```

- When I try to execute I have a syntax error but I cannot figure out
  where is the problem: *"#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;
  check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for
  the right syntax to use near 'WHILE CONT > 1 DO BEGIN SELECT
  TableA.ColumnA INTO OUTFILE CONCAT('OUT'' at line 4"*
- How to execute this stored procedure?

Comment: Maybe you are missing a ";" at the end of "END WHILE", and probably also at the ends of some other lines, e.g. the line beginning with "DECLARE"? How comes that you get an error when you try to execute this, but then you ask how to execute it? I am confused :-) I would assume that you execute it with "CALL dowhile();"

Comment: No, if I put a ";" after the DECLARE line I get: -> BEGIN
    ->   DECLARE CONT INT DEFAULT 5;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3. I am pasting the "script" to the mysql interpreter, how comes that the mysql interpreter sometimes executes sentences by putting a ";" and sometimes by using a CALL? ;) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like 2 problems:

- the mysql-client interprets any ";" before it hands down the procedure to the server, therefore you have to set a different delimiter first
- you cannot use a dynamic filename as into outfile like you tried it here

With a lot of google-search I came to the following solution that worked with my MySql 5.1.51:

```
delimiter //

CREATE PROCEDURE doWhile()
BEGIN
  DECLARE CONT INT DEFAULT 5;
  DECLARE filename VARCHAR(32);
  WHILE CONT > 1 DO
        SET @myvar = CONCAT('SELECT TableA.ColumnB INTO OUTFILE', "'", CONCAT('OUT', CONT), "'", 'FROM TableA WHERE TableA.ColumnA = ', CONT );
        PREPARE stmt1 FROM @myvar;
        EXECUTE stmt1;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
        SET CONT = CONT - 1;
  END WHILE;
END
```